# How to find the smallest number exceeding $n$ with at least $m$ prime factors

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algorithms, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

I'm wondering if there is a clever way to find the next number containing at least $m$ prime factors (not necessarily distinct) after a given number $n = p_1 \dots p_{m+k}$ given with prime factors.

**Example:** ($m := 2$)
$$
n_0 = 2 \cdot 2 = 4 \\
n_1 = 2 \cdot 3 = 6 \\
n_3 = 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 = 8 \\
n_4 = 3 \cdot 3 = 9 \\
n_5 = 2 \cdot 5 = 10
$$

This is relatively easy, since for $m = 2$ only the prime numbers will be missing in this series. But how would I proceed if I was given $m$ and a number $n = p_1 \cdot ... \cdot p_{m+k}$ ($k \in \mathbb{N_o}, \;\;p_1, ... p_{m+k}$ primes in ascending order)?

How could I find the smallest number greater $n$ with at least $m$ prime factors?

Comment: A short piece of PARI/GP code will do this well, provided $n$ is not too large.  Would that work for you?

Comment: Depends on how big $m$ is, how big $n$ is, and what you call "clever". E.g., to find the next number after $10^{10}$ with at least 6 prime factors, well, the smallest number with 6 primes factors is $2^6=64$, so at least one of the numbers $10^{10}+1,\dots,10^{10}+64$ has at least 6 prime factors, so it's just a matter of factoring a few 11-digit numbers. Is that clever?

Comment: @MatthewConroy It would be nice if one found a good way to find the next prime factors of the next number with at least $m$ factors given the prime factors of the current number.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I'd prefer a method, which finds the prime-factors of the next number given the prime-factors of the current number (combines the factors or something).

Comment: I guess there is no better method than just brute force. In general, determining the number of prime factors is as hard as factoring. If $m$ is large, then you can possibly apply trial division upto a relatively low limit to get your number.

Comment: Knowing the number of prime factors of $n$ tells you virtually nothing about the number of prime factors of numbers near $n$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson What about knowing _the prime factors_ of $n$?

Comment: Knowing everything there is to know about $n$ tells you virtually nothing about the number of prime factors of numbers near $n$. For instance, $2^m$ has no secrets, but that's of very little help if you want to know something about $2^m+3$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Why is it necessary to take the approach to look at numbers near $n$ to find the next number containing at least $m$ prime factors. This is how I'm looking at the problem: Let's say $m = 2 \cdot 3 = 6$. If we want at least $2$ prime factors we have three possibilities: Add another prime factor to increase $n$. If this is the right way to increase $m$  the added prime factor will be $2$ for sure (since this is the smallest prime). Another possibility is to replace one prime number with a bigger prime ($3 \cdot 3 = 9$ or $ 2 \cdot 5 = 10)$...

Comment: The third possibility is to combine multiple primes with one or more other primes $(2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \rightarrow 3 \cdot 3)$.

Comment: OK, how does this apply to finding the next number after $10^{10}$ with at least six prime factors? The tricks you mention will, I think give numbers way bigger than $10^{10}+64$. How do you propose to decide whether there's an answer smaller than $10^{10}+64$? or the next number after the prime 6700417 with at least six prime factors?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I'll need to think about the number after $10^{10}$ with at least $6$ prime numbers, but you may have misunderstood my question: The given number $n$ has already contains at least $6$ prime numbers. So asking for the next number with at least $6$ prime factors after the prime 6700517 is not part of the question.

Comment: What's the difference? When looking for the next number after $n$ with at least six prime factors, what difference does it make, how many prime factors $n$ has?